# How to iterate over the result of strapi.db.query?

Tags: javascript, loops, strapi, iterable

I have a simple `findMany` query in my controller:

```
const appointments = strapi.db.query("api::appointment.appointment").findMany({
    select: ["date", "startTime", "endTime"],
    where: {
        mentorId: mentorId,
        status: [1, 2, 4]
    }
});
```

It returns the following, such structure made me think that the result returned is iterable.

```
[
    {
        "date":"2022-04-27",
        "startTime":"08:00:00.000",
        "endTime":"10:00:00.000"
    },
    {
        "date":"2022-04-27",
        "startTime":"10:00:00.000",
        "endTime":"12:00:00.000"
    }
]
```

However, when I use a `for` loop, I can tell that it didn't even enter since there's no output.

```
for (let appointment in appointments)
    console.log("I entered");
```

When I used `forEach`, I got `error: appointments.forEach is not a function`.

```
appointments.foreach(function(appointment) {
    console.log(appointment.date);
});
```

So, I then checked if it is iterable using `Symbol.iterator in Object(appointments)`, but it returns `false`. `Array.isArray(appointments)` also returns `false` which is weird, because the result definitely looked like an array to me.

Is there any workaround for this? I need to loop through each object, and access its fields.

**EDIT - Entire Controller File:**

```
"use strict";

/**
 *  availability controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreController("api::availability.availability", ({strapi}) => ({
    async getFreeSlots(ctx) {
        const mentorId = ctx.params.mentorId;

        const appointments = strapi.db.query("api::appointment.appointment").findMany({
            select: ["date", "startTime", "endTime"],
            where: {
                mentorId: mentorId,
                status: [1, 2, 4]
            }
        });
        console.log(appointments);

        return appointments;
    }
}));
```

Comment: It's `.forEach()` with a capital E

Comment: @Aioros Oh yea, sorry about that. I edited it now. Anyways, I'm still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.findMany()` method is asynchronous and returns a Promise. I suppose you are instead trying to use it synchronously right after the call. You need to `await` it.

```
const appointments = await strapi.db.query("api::appointment.appointment").findMany({
    select: ["date", "startTime", "endTime"],
    where: {
        mentorId: mentorId,
        status: [1, 2, 4]
    }
});
console.log(appointments);
```

Alternatively, if you are not in an `async` function (that's needed to use `await`), you can use the classic `.then()` from the Promise:

```
strapi.db.query("api::appointment.appointment").findMany({
    select: ["date", "startTime", "endTime"],
    where: {
        mentorId: mentorId,
        status: [1, 2, 4]
    }
}).then((appointments) => {
    console.log(appointments);
    /*...*/
});
```

Comment: I'm in an `async` function, and after adding `await`, I'm still getting the same behavior.

Comment: Do you mind showing the relevant code all together? Especially the part where you are able to see the result structure that you have in your question.

Comment: I added `consoloe.log(appointments)`, and it showed `Promise { <pending> }` although I already added the `await` keyword. I got the array looking result (from `return appointments;`) by visiting the URL that I have set in my router. I edited my post to include the entire controller file.

Comment: Thanks for the added code, but it's still missing the `await`

Comment: It's working now. Turns out, I wasn't able to save the file before restarting the server, sorry.